# VESA flush wall-mount with height adjustment

Tags: monitors, monitor-stand

I use a single 43" Samsung monitor with a "standing" desk (which I can raise and lower between sitting height and standing height for work).

I need the monitor's height to adjust independent of the desk's (I like it higher when I'm standing relative to the desk than when I'm sitting), and it's a little shaky on the desk anyway.

So I want a height-adjustable wall-mount for the monitor.

But I have been unable to find VESA wall-mounts that simply flush-mount the monitor and make it easy to lift and lower it (at least 20").  Every "height-adjustable" VESA wall-mount I have found is still on an arm, so it significantly changes the distance from the wall as the height is changed.

Is anyone aware of VESA wall-mount that offers easy height adjustments with no other dependent degrees of freedom?